# How to detect which symbol was clicked in DIV or SPAN?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is that possible to find position of symblol, which was clicked in DIV or SPAN? My task is to divide this DIV into two DIVs in point where the click was done.
I use jQuery.

Symbol I mean character. Or rather position of this character (its number in DIV).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
$('div').click( function () {
    console.log(getSelectionPosition()); 
});


function getSelectionPosition () {
    var selection = window.getSelection();    
    return selection.focusOffset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [pageX](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/) and [pageY](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageY/) properties of the jQuery event object.

You'll then have to do some calculations against the position of the element in the DOM since it's overall page position, not actual position.